Always encrypted with Entity Framework Core
We have a .NET Core application with EF Core 7 and code-first approach.
We have taken the below steps:

Create table in the database
Encrypt columns using Always Encrypted - with keys in Azure Key Vault
Changed connection string to include "Column Encryption Setting=enabled'"

We have used the clientid, clientSecret and TenantId to register in keyvault and that seems to connect and work with the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient library.
This is the code:

Is there a way to make this work directly from Entity Framework Core and not use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient library?

EF Core uses Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, so not sure you need to do anything

Is there any way to make it work without separately using SqlClient for the SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider?
